# How to save image server side when send from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

I'm was making a drag and drop upload script by reading a bunch of tutorials, but they only cover the javascript part, and i'm having issues on the php part.

I'm uploading a image as this:

```
$('#drop-zone').bind('drop', drop);

function drop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    traverseFiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
}
```

traverseFiles makes a foreach loop for every file and calls upload funcion, there i do this:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

//some event listners for processing, on load

xhr.open("post", "core/plugins/upload/upload.class.php", true);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type);

xhr.send(file);
```

then in php i found using this will get me raw data of the image

```
$file = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

EDIT: solution found

```
$fh = fopen($savedir, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $file);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: by the way, $_POST and $_FILES are both empty when i use this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have managed to get the raw file from the PHP input, it's likely going to be base64 encoded. A simple example would be to do this:

```
<?php
//decode file
$image = base64_decode($file);

// write it
$filename = "myfile.png";
$fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $image);
fclose($fh);
```

**Edit**
See comments, the file wasn't encoded as a result of the request.

Comment: Thanks ill take a look at your answer and see how it goes

Comment: It wasnt encoded, when i used fwrite instead of move_uploaded_file it alredy works, thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`move_uploaded_file` is not what you want.  If you had sent the file with a normal POST request (rather than through Ajax), that's when you'd use `move_uploaded_file`.

`$file` contains the raw binary data for the image.  All you have to do is write that data into a file (taking note to properly handle linebreaks) and you're good to go.  Start with `fopen` and see how far you get.

I'm assuming that `$file` has been successfully populated with the binary data and that you've tested this.  If not, then you've got  another problem on the javascript side.

Edit: you may also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542741/how-come-php-is-not-writing-the-image-contents-to-disk/9543173) helpful.

Comment: Not a direct solution but still a nice awnser i can use that post as example towards improving my code. Thanks!