# Moving animated gif file using imagegif causes it to lose animation

Tags: php, animated-gif

I have a script that uploads an image using JavaScript, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785948/how-to-save-image-server-side-when-send-from-javascript).

I solved the problem from that post. Now I take the contents from the JavaScript call and save it to a temp_file. After that I resize it, rename etc and save it to
a final location.

It works fine until I try to do it with a .gif (I skip all resizing on .gifs).

Here is how I do it:

```
//$filename = the temp_image that is alredy stored (animated gif)
$this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);

header('Content-Type: image/gif');

imagegif($this->image,$savepath);

unlink($filename);
```

The temp_file is still animated, but after moving it to `$savepath` it loses its animation.

What could cause this to happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to copy a file from input to output, why parse it?! Just move the file:

```
move_uploaded_file($filename, $savepath);
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP's GD library does not support animated GIFs. You'll need to use [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) instead.

Comment: I wish to use these scripts on a web-host meaning i only have ftp access ... I can't install imagemagick, any other solutions? i don't need to resize the gif's only move them

Comment: Why did you say "then using that i **resize**, rename etc" then?!

Comment: i think you missed the next line saying "(i skip all resizing on .gifs)" anyways looks like i looked over the solution myself but its solved now, thanks for your input and effort!